# Dataset values in array

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS, I want my datalines value to be stored in a array
I want the 10 20 30 to be stored in an array

```
enter code here
data array;
input num 2.;
array arr[3] a1-a3;
datalines;
10
20
30
;
run;
proc print data=array;
```

expected one is a1=10;a2=20;a3=30;

Comment: Arrays are not objects in SAS, they don't exist outside a data step so not sure you're going to get what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.

Here is a possibility:

```
data array;
array arr{*} a1-a3;
do i=1 to 3;
    arr{i}=10*i;
end;
output;
drop i;
run;

proc print data=array;
run;
```

Note that you can't print the value of the array after the datastep, so if you want to print values, they have to be in the *dataset* `array`, either in a column or in a line. Here the array maps to *variables* a1, a2, a3, which are then set with a loop (a `cards` statement would also do, but then why use an array?), hence you end up with a single row in your dataset.

Suggested reading: [Using Arrays in SAS Programming](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/97529_Using_Arrays_in_SAS_Programming.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not objects in SAS. You can create a data set or you can create macro variables. I suspect you're new to SAS so I'd recommend staying away from macros and instead work with data steps and SQL for now.

You can create a data set with the values and use them later on though. If you explain how you'd like to use them later, we can probably suggest the appropriate data structure.

If you do want to have array's and matrices you need to use PROC IML to have that type of functionality which is very different than Base SAS and more similar to R/Python.

```
data array;
infile cards missover;
input a b c 2.;
datalines;
10 20 30
;
run;
```